# Include a *.cpp file

Tags: c++, bazel

Currently, I try to bazelize a library. Let's call this library *lib_foo*.

The setup is similar to this minimal example. My main application tries to use a function form *lib_foo*.

main.cpp:

```
#include "lib_foo/header.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << foo<2>() << std::endl;
}
```

lib_foo/header.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "impl.inc" // works
```

lib_foo/impl.inc:

```
template <int number>
int foo() {
    return number;    
}
```

BUILD.bazel:

```
cc_library(
    name = "lib_foo",
    srcs = [
        "lib_foo/header.h",
        "lib_foo/impl.inc",
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    srcs = [
        "main.cpp",
    ],
    deps = [":lib_foo"],
)
```

There is also an empty `WORKSPACE` file.

If I run `bazel run //:HelloWorld` everything works as expected.

If I rename the file `impl.inc` to `impl.cpp` (and change this accordingly in BUILD and include file, etc.). I run in the following problem (on Ubuntu 20.04):

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
lib_foo/header.h:3:10: fatal error: impl.cpp: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "impl.cpp"
    |          ^~~~~~~~~
```

Also replacing the include path with a relative one to the WORKSPACE file does not help here.

It seems that it is a general problem to include cpp files in Bazel. Since the third party library I try to bazelize does include several times cpp files I wonder what a proper workaround here is.

Any ideas?

(I am using Bazel 3.7.2 on Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: The common parlance is to compile a .cpp file and *link it* to other cpp files (including main); not many projects use `#include` with .cpp files.

Comment: Another common practice is to compile `.cpp` files into a library, then link in the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal workaround is to put includable cpp files in the [`textual_hdrs`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.textual_hdrs) attribute of `cc_library`.